# Keypress is not called anymore after form inside jquery ui modal box is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery UI modal box that contains a form.

I declared keypress event to handle Enter being pressed.
If I hide the form contained in the modal box, the keypress event is not called anymore.

This behaviour is reproduced here: https://jsfiddle.net/patrick29/jqp4wp77/

```
$('.dialog').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) {
        submit();
    }
});
function submit() {
    alert('ok');
    $('.dialog form').hide();
}
```

First time Enter is pressed I receive ok message. Then form is hidden and second time Enter is pressed I do not receive ok message anymore.

Do you know why and how I can hide form and still have keypress event work ?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's hidden, how can it have focus so that you can press keys inside it?

Comment: The ok button is the one of the modal box which is not hidden, so I expected hiding the form would not change keypress event management on modal box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this instead of .hide();

```
$('.dialog form').css({
  opacity: 0
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nr5fptd2/1/

Comment: It works but I want space occupied by form to disappear, which is not the case with setting opacity to 0

Comment: function submit() {alert('ok');
    $('.dialog').css({
     minHeight: '0px',
      height: 0,
      opacity: 0
    });
  }

Comment: As I did not found any clean solution I used a workaround inspired from yours `function submit() {alert('ok'); $('dialog').css({'position':'absolute','left':'-500px'}); }` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To have a keypress handler on a container, you need to have inside an element that supports keyboard interactions, like an input. No elements inside the .dialog div support that once you hide the form. More information here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201302/making_elements_keyboard_focusable_and_clickable/

Adding `$('.dialog').append('<input/>');` in your submit function, for example, will make the event work. Of course, I don't recommend it.

Comment: I tried your adding $('.dialog').append('<input/>'); in my submit function but the result is the same (keypress event is not handled after form is deleted)